# Fusion charts free: How to keep charts behind to all objects in website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion chart and binding it from ASP.NET code behind. Below is the code.

Here is the chart xml:

```
<graph  lineThickness='1' showValues='1'  formatNumberScale='0' anchorRadius='2' anchorBgAlpha='0' divLineAlpha ='50' numVDivLines='29' vDivlineAlpha ='50' vDivlineThickness='2'  vDivlineColor ='C0C0C0' DivlineColor ='C0C0C0'  numDivLines='9' showAlternateHGridColor='0'  rotateNames='1'  adjustDiv='0' useRoundEdges='1' yAxisValueDecimals='0'  shadowAlpha='0' decimalPrecision='0' yAxisMaxValue='100'  canvasbordercolor = 'C0C0C0' yAxisMinValue='0' divLineColor='C0C0C0'anchorborderthickness='1' rotateValues='1' placeValuesInside='1' valuePosition='ABOVE'>
```

and below is the code behind code from where I bind the chart to literal control.

```
ltrlFCSource.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("../FlashFiles/FCF_MSLine.swf", "", ChartXML, "sourceReputationChart", "550", "245", false);
```

Can anyone help me how to keep the chart in behind to all objects? Currently it is appearing in front of all objects in my ASP.Net page. Please see below the image for easier reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `wMode` property of the swf to anything except `window`. From FusionCharts API perspective it is equivalent to setting `.setTransparent(false)`.

Comment: Where can I set this property?

Comment: In swfobject. I will have to look up. Don't have the files anywhere around!!